# Is it possible to have dynamic binding in R?

Tags: r

Is it possible to have a variable with a dynamic binding in R? Say, to have something like this to work:

```
f1a <- function() {
  x <- 1
  f2()
}

f1b <- function() {
  x <- 2
  f2()
}

f2 <- function() {
  f3()
}

f3 <- function() {
  # print x
}

f1a() # prints 1
f1b() # prints 2
```

I can pass `x` down the stack explicitly, but that is not what I'm looking for. I'm asking about a possibility for a dynamic binding. I understand that many people would say passing `x` explicitly is *always* preferable, but suppose I cannot change the definition of `f2` (I can change `f1a`, `f1b` and `f3`). I can have a global variable, of course, but I'd rather use a dynamic binding if possible.

Comment: If you don't want to use the global environment, could you execute the function `f2` in a new environment where your `x` is available?

Comment: I've tried `do.call(f2, list(), envir = env)` earlier, but `f3` does not seem to inherit `env`. My understanding, the environment for `f2` and for it's call to `f3` gets assigned at definition time, and it's the global environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f1a <- function() {
  x <- 1
  f2()
}

f1b <- function() {
  x <- 2
  f2()
}

f2 <- function() {
  f3()
}

f3 <- function() {
  get("x", envir = parent.frame(2))
}
```

Simply move the environment in which `f3` is looking for the variable `x`.

```
> f1a()
[1] 1
> f1b()
[1] 2
```

`get("x", envir = parent.frame(2))` looks for a variable with symbol `x` in an environment two frames up the call stack:

```
f3 <- function() {
  get("x", envir = parent.frame(2))
  rlang::trace_back()
}

> f1a()
    █
 1. └─global::f1a()
 2.   └─global::f2()
 3.     └─global::f3()
```

If you need to iterate up an entire call stack until the first of a symbol is encountered, simply use `dynGet()`:

```
f1a <- function() {
  x <- 1
  f2()
}

f1b <- function() {
  x <- 2
  f2()
}

f2 <- function() {
  f3()
}

f3 <- function() {
  f4()
}

f4 <- function() {
  f5()
}

f5 <- function() {
  dynGet("x")
}

> f1a()
[1] 1
> f1b()
[1] 2
```

This will stop at the first `x` encountered moving up the call stack from the calling environment. So if we adjust `f2`:

```
f2 <- function() {
  x <- 3
  f3()
}

> f1a()
[1] 3
> f1b()
[1] 3
```

Again, the full call stack can be seen with `rlang::trace_back`:

```
f5 <- function() {
  dynGet("x")
  rlang::trace_back()
}

> f1a()
    █
 1. └─global::f1a()
 2.   └─global::f2()
 3.     └─global::f3()
 4.       └─global::f4()
 5.         └─global::f5()
```

Comment: Suppose I don't know the stack size. What would be the way to get the "closest" binding of `x`. Simply iterate over the stack to find it?

Comment: LOL, I fooled myself. I checked the documentation for `get`, saw `dynGet` and tried it, but it didn't work, so I posted my comment. What I tried was `print(dynGet("x"))` however, and I guess `x` is used in `print` and that's where it went wrong... Thanks, `dynGet` is precisely what I've been looking for.

Comment: If you need to use `print` for whatever reason, just first assign the output of `dynget("x")` to a variable within the function scope, then call print on that:   `x <- dynGet("x"); print(x)`